# Rails - Group by 2 date columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, group-by

Using Rails and PostgreSQL how can I group by two DATETIME columns?

I want to format a string based on the weekdays of a establishment is open

Eg: MON-FRI 10:00 - 22:00, SAT-SUN 10:00 - 18:00

I have this model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: establishment_open_hours
#
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  weekday             :string
#  opens_at            :datetime
#  closes_at           :datetime
#  openable_hours_id   :integer
#  openable_hours_type :string
#  created_at          :datetime
#  updated_at          :datetime
#

class Establishment::OpenHour < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :openable_hours, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Provide few more details **we are not Chuck Norris**

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. An Establishment has_many open_hours. I want to group open_hours by two DATETIME columns (opens_at and closes_at) so I can format a human friendly string

Comment: What values do you have in weekday?

Comment: also, do you want the result like weekdays, weekend, weekdays, weekend

Comment: Weekdays are:
MON
FRI
...

Comment: I want to group days with similar opens_at and closes_at time. Not always will be weekday/weekend